# Likeable 10 letter words

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, pattern

This is a list of some of the 10 letter words that are liked and disliked by *Adam*.

| Like | Dislike |
| --- | --- |
| Idealogues | Audiometry |
| Impoundage | Equivocacy |
| Inoculated | Iceboating |
| Inosculate | Outpatient |
| Ionopauses | Ultrasonic |

---

This is a list of some of the 10 letter words that are liked and disliked by *Brian*.

| Like | Dislike |
| --- | --- |
| Absolution | Denudation |
| Exhaustion | Hesitation |
| Insulation | Nauseation |
| Occupation | Refraction |
| Ulceration | Regulation |

---

This is a list of some of the 10 letter words that are liked and disliked by *Charles*.

| Like | Dislike |
| --- | --- |
| Aquiferous | Disastrous |
| Endogamous | Jaspideous |
| Infectious | Precarious |
| Olivaceous | Soniferous |
| Unperilous | Violaceous |

---

1. ***Which is the only 10 letter word that will be liked by both Adam and Brian?***
2. ***Which is the only 10 letter word that will be liked by both Adam and Charles?***

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. INEQUATION; 2. IRIDACEOUS

Reasoning:

> This puzzle seems to be about the regular vowels AEIOU, as hinted by the beginning letters of Brian and Charles' liked lists.

> Adam likes words which contain all 5 vowels and begin with 'I'.

> Brian likes words which begin with a vowel and end with 'TION'.

> Charles likes words which begin with a vowel and end with 'OUS'.

Which is the only 10 letter word that will be liked by both Adam and Brian?

> Checking against [a default qat list](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=10%3Ai%28%2Faeou.....%29+%26+*tion&ent=Search&dict=6), the only answer is INEQUATION.

Which is the only 10 letter word that will be liked by both Adam and Charles?

> Checking against [a default qat list](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=10%3Ai%28%2Faeou.....%29+%26+*ous&ent=Search&dict=0), the only answer is IRIDACEOUS.

Comment: I've added qat links to your answer to help demonstrate to users who may not know what qat is. However, it seems the second answer is really dependent on dictionary choice - using the union of all available dictionaries suggests there are [5 potential answers](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=10%3Ai%28%2Faeou.....%29+%26+*ous&ent=Search&dict=6) for that one... (Not at all saying you're wrong - your answer certainly looks like what the OP intended!)